Who is the Dharma Deva described in Mahabharata?
It is mentioned in the Mahabharata (Parva 17: Mahaprasthanika, Chapter 3) that a dog was following Yudhisthira.

Vaishampayana continued: 'Hearing these words of king Yudhishthira the just, (the dog became transformed into) the deity of Righteousness, who, well pleased, said these words unto him in a sweet voice fraught with praise.

There was another encounter between Dharma and Yudhisthira which he reminded him of.

Formerly, O son, thou wert once examined by me in the woods of Dwaita, where thy brothers of great prowess met with (an appearance of) death. Disregarding both thy brothers Bhima and Arjuna, thou didst wish for the revival of Nakula from thy desire of doing good to thy (step-) mother.

Later the Dharma Deva accompanied Yudhisthira when he went to heaven along with other deities.

Vaishampayana continued: 'Then Dharma, and Shakra, and the Maruts, and the Ashvinis, and other deities, and the celestial Rishis, causing Yudhishthira to ascend on a car, proceeded to Heaven.

Yudhisthira is also known as Dharmaputra (the Son of Dharma). Who is this deity of Righteousness or Dharma Deva? How does he look? Who is his vahana? Do we still worship this deity?

Yamadeva the lord of righteousness(Yamraj)

Dharma is the mind-born son of Brahma, who is the husband of Daksa's 13 daughters & serves Bhagavana Shiva as his bull. Yama, who is known as Dharmaraja, is the son of Surya through his wife Samjna, is the brother of Yamuna, Ikshvaku, Vaivasvata Manu, half-brother of Sanaiscara, Tapati & Savarni Manu, regent of the South, who was vanquished by Bahagvana Shiva.

@অনু. OK. So, there are two Dharmas. Then who is this Dharma (who is talking to Yudhishthira)? Brahma's mind-born son or Surya's son?

@অনু Dharmathakur is worshipped in rural Bengal. Does he have any connection to this dharma deva?

@AmritenduMukhopadhyay Dharma, the biological father of Yudhisthira is the mind-born son of Brahma. And Dharmathakur of Bengal is more likely associated with Baraham baba of Mithila.
